# Returning json object from javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, fullcalendar

I'm working with fullcalendar, and the google calendar api where I get my events out and want to deliver them to my fullcalendar as json since the fullcalendar event accept that as a datasource and automatically renders them into the calendar.

I have my html file which includes a number of ressources and a jQuery script that creates the calendar:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel='stylesheet' href='fullcalendar/fullcalendar.css' />
        <script src='fullcalendar/lib/jquery.min.js'></script>
        <script src='fullcalendar/lib/moment.min.js'></script>
        <script src='fullcalendar/fullcalendar.js'></script>
        <script type='text/javascript' src='fullcalendar/gcal.js'></script>
        <script src='fullcalendar/lang/da.js'></script>

        <script type='text/javascript'>
            $(document).ready(function() {
                $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
                    defaultView: 'agendaWeek',
                    weekends: false,
                    lang: 'da',
                    header: false,
                    allDaySlot: false,
                    allDayText: '',
                    height: 695,
                    minTime: '06:00:00',
                    maxTime: '20:00:00',
                    events: 'calendarData.js'
                });
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="calendar"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Notice the events: that takes the json object in. I have a json file with identical hardcoded json object as the one i'm trying to create and that works fine. But something fails/is wrong in the following javascript file.

calendarData.js

```
var CLIENT_ID = 'id';

var SCOPES = ["https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar.readonly"];

/**
 * Check if current user has authorized this application.
 */
function checkAuth() {
    gapi.auth.authorize(
        {
            'client_id': CLIENT_ID,
            'scope': SCOPES.join(' '),
            'immediate': true
        }, handleAuthResult);
}

/**
 * Handle response from authorization server.
 *
 * @param {Object} authResult Authorization result.
 */
function handleAuthResult(authResult) {
    var authorizeDiv = document.getElementById('authorize-div');
    if (authResult && !authResult.error) {
        // Hide auth UI, then load client library.
        authorizeDiv.style.display = 'none';
        loadCalendarApi();
    } else {
        // Show auth UI, allowing the user to initiate authorization by
        // clicking authorize button.
        authorizeDiv.style.display = 'inline';
    }
}

/**
 * Initiate auth flow in response to user clicking authorize button.
 *
 * @param {Event} event Button click event.
 */
function handleAuthClick(event) {
    gapi.auth.authorize(
        {client_id: CLIENT_ID, scope: SCOPES, immediate: false},
        handleAuthResult);
    return false;
}

/**
 * Load Google Calendar client library. List upcoming events
 * once client library is loaded.
 */
function loadCalendarApi() {
    gapi.client.load('calendar', 'v3', listUpcomingEvents);
}

/**
 * Print the summary and start datetime/date of the next ten events in
 * the authorized user's calendar. If no events are found an
 * appropriate message is printed.
 */
function listUpcomingEvents() {
    var request = gapi.client.calendar.events.list({
        'calendarId': 'primary',
        'timeMin': (new Date()).toISOString(),
        'showDeleted': false,
        'singleEvents': true,
        'maxResults': 10,
        'orderBy': 'startTime'
    });
    var json = {};

    request.execute(function(resp) {
        var events = resp.items;
        json.json = [];

        if (events.length > 0) {
            for (i = 0; i < events.length; i++) {
                var event = events[i];
                var when = event.start.dateTime;
                if (!when) {
                    when = event.start.date;
                }
                json.json.push({id : i+1, title : event.summary, start : event.start.dateTime, end : event.end.dateTime, desc : event.description});
            }
        }
    });
    return json;
}
```

As you might see this is very close to the api calendar javascript quickstart apart from the json at the end. I would like the script to return a json object to the fullcalendar but this doesn't work, so how could I change this if possible?

When i stringify and alert the object I can see that the object created is the same as the previously mentioned json file that does work.

Edit:
The json file i'm talking about and which data can be used looks like this:

```
[{"id":"1","title":"Test 1","start":"2016-05-26","end":"2016-05-26T16:30:00","allDay":false},{"id":"2","title":"Test 2","start":"2016-05-26","end":"2016-05-26T17:00:00","allDay":false},{"id":"3","title":"Test 3","start":"2016-05-27T08:00:00","end":"","allDay":false}]
```

When I stringify and alert the object it looks like this:

```
var myObject = JSON.stringify(json);
            alert(myObject);
{"json":[{"id":1,"title":"ghhgfgh","start":"2016-05-26T14:30:00+02:00","end":"2016-05-26T15:30:00+02:00"}]}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is here:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    defaultView: 'agendaWeek',
    weekends: false,
    lang: 'da',
    header: false,
    allDaySlot: false,
    allDayText: '',
    height: 695,
    minTime: '06:00:00',
    maxTime: '20:00:00',
    events: 'calendarData.js'
  });
});
```

The "events" can't get a javascript file as an input nor as a direct json string. You can give it an [array of events](http://fullcalendar.io/docs/event_data/events_array/), a [URL](http://fullcalendar.io/docs/event_data/events_json_feed/) or a [function](http://fullcalendar.io/docs/event_data/events_function/).

I guess you intended to feed the "events" with the results of **listUpcomingEvents()** function.

You can do it that way (just make sure your you add the **calendarData.js** as script src in your HTML file as well):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    defaultView: 'agendaWeek',
    weekends: false,
    lang: 'da',
    header: false,
    allDaySlot: false,
    allDayText: '',
    height: 695,
    minTime: '06:00:00',
    maxTime: '20:00:00',
    events: function(start, end, timezone, callback){
              callback(listUpcomingEvents());
            },
  });
});
```

Comment: Thanks, yeah that does it. Only problem is it seems the authentication breaks down somewhere when I add it into a function. For instance function getData() { var json = []; json.push('some hardcoded data'); return json;} works fine with the above function call. But if i add the calendarData.js into a function in a script in the html file no data is added to array. And I know for a sure it works since it runs and gets data in another file without the jQuery. But that's not a direct fullcalendar issue.

Answer (score 0):

To interract between JS / JSON object you've to use:

```
JSON.stringify()
JSON.parse()
```

Reference are [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) and [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse)

For example: JS > JSON > JS

```
var x = {
y: 'hello',
z: 1
};

console.log(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(x)));
```

Answer (score 0):

convert it into JSON object like this:

```
var Jobj = JSON.parse(your_string_data);
```

Comment: So would that be var Jobj = JSON.parse(json); return Jobj; ? Also added some more on the json element as it looks now.

Comment: you can return the object where ever you want.